# Laravel Manipulate user data before send it to session when user log in

Tags: laravel, parsing, authentication, session

I'm actually creating an administrative panel, all my users have a column 'permissions' on DB that store a JSON table in TEXT format.
Actually when a user log in this column is stored in 'permissions' variable on session, but in TEXT, i need to parse it to json in order to make an object before store it.
Someone know how can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can decode JSON with `json_decode`:

```
$permissions = json_decode($user->permissions);
```

Though if you are using Eloquent Model's I would just cast this field to an array so it handles the encoding and decoding to and from JSON for you:

```
protected $casts = [
    'permissions' => 'array',
];
```

Now when you access this `permissions` property of the Model it will return the decoded data:

```
$user->permissions;
```